# How to get deque elements via indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, queue, deque

I have the following deque object:

```
test = deque([np.zeros((4,1,1))+0.5] * 25)
```

So there are 25 arrays of some shape, and I will be appending in objects, popping off old ones on the other end, etc.

At some point I will want to select a subset of elements in my deque:

```
>>> idx = np.round(np.linspace(0, 20, 4, dtype='int'))
>>> idx
array([ 0,  6, 13, 20])
```

So I want those indicies. I tried:

```
>>> test[idx]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Perhaps deque doesn't support this type of indexing operation. How can I easily (and efficiently) get a list of the elements in `idx` from `test` ?

EDIT --

More info on my original goal. I have a list of 3D numpy arrays, i.e. `(N, H,W,3)` and in real time I am shifting a new 3D array into the list of `N`, i.e. a new array of size `(H,W,3)` gets shifted (like a queue) into the list of N.

It would be nice to just have a numpy array of shape `(N, H,W,3)` for everything, but I couldn't figure out how to get efficient queue functionality so I went with `deque`.

Comment: @miradulo That seems to work -- would this be efficient though?

Comment: Well this is the way to index a deque with a bunch of indices in Python, which is generally slow. Whether your work here in general is efficient, I have no idea. I've never seen someone using a deque of NumPy arrays before.. and would think that adding a dimension to your NumPy array instead, fixing the size and avoiding this entirely (if possible) would be the efficient thing to do.

Comment: My original idea was to add a numpy array index and use np.roll, but that was found to be very slow rather than using deque. Open to other ideas.

Comment: accessing an index using a deque is `O(n)`, unlike `list`. Python has to follow n links to reach the object.

Comment: @JDS If you added some information on what problem you're actually solving, it would be a lot easier to suggest an efficient solution.

Comment: Sure I'll edit question. Check it out now, maybe should have started with that.

Comment: "So there are 25 arrays of some shape" - no, there's only one array, which you made 25 references to.

Comment: Also, indexing into the middle of a deque is inefficient, since `collections.deque` is an unrolled linked list instead of a ring buffer. It's probably fine for a deque this small, but not for larger ones.

Comment: `deque` uses scalar indexing like a list, e.g. `[test[i] for i in idx]`.  I just did some timings comparing with the same on `a=list(test)`, and got the same times.

Answer (score 3):

To directly answer your question, you index a deque with an iterable of indices the same as you do a list - `[test[i] for i in idx]`. But deque random lookup is `O(n)` (which could matter more for larger deques), and if you want to do NumPy-style indexing into the deque you won't be able to. From your problem description it also sounds like you're looking for a ring buffer.

So instead of the deque at all, it might be a better idea (and more efficient  for larger deque sizes) to stick to NumPy.

Now you could roll your own deque-like ring buffer interface class around an ndarray that manages the size of the buffer, left/right indices, etc.. Or Eric Weiser has already released [`numpy_ringbuffer`](https://github.com/eric-wieser/numpy_ringbuffer) which seems well-suited for your problem.

**Demo**

```
In [83]: from numpy_ringbuffer import RingBuffer

In [84]: # RingBuffer w/ capacity 3, extra dimensions (2, 2)
    ...: r = RingBuffer(capacity=3, dtype=(float, (2, 2)))

In [85]: # fill our buffer up
    ...: r.extendleft(np.arange(12, dtype=float).reshape(3, 2, 2))

In [86]: r.is_full
Out[86]: True

In [87]: r
Out[87]: 
<RingBuffer of array([[[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  3.]],

       [[ 4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.]],

       [[ 8.,  9.],
        [10., 11.]]])>

In [88]: r.appendleft(np.arange(12, 16).reshape(2, 2))

In [89]: r
Out[89]: 
<RingBuffer of array([[[12., 13.],
        [14., 15.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  3.]],

       [[ 4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.]]])>
```

You get a minimal deque interface with `append`, `extend`, `pop` and left versions. You can also use NumPy indexing on the underlying array.

```
In [90]: r[[0, 2]]
Out[90]: 
array([[[12., 13.],
        [14., 15.]],

       [[ 4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.]]])
```

Compared to a naive approach to deque-like operations in NumPy, it will be much quicker, since it is just manipulating left/right indices wherever possible.

```
In [91]: arr = np.random.randn(10**7).reshape(10**5, 10, 10)

In [92]: r = RingBuffer(capacity=arr.shape[0],
    ...:                dtype=(float, arr.shape[1:]))
    ...:                

In [93]: %%timeit r.extendleft(arr); s = np.random.randn(10, 10)
    ...: r.appendleft(s)
    ...: r.append(s)
    ...: 
4.08 µs ± 66.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [94]: %%timeit A=arr.copy(); s = np.random.randn(10, 10)
    ...: A[1:] = A[:-1]
    ...: A[0] = s
    ...: A[:-1] = A[1:]
    ...: A[-1] = s
    ...: 
91.5 ms ± 231 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like to dive in the `numpy` algebra You may give the [`blist`](https://pypi.org/project/blist/) package a try which allows very quick index access. It gives you the advantages of both worlds of `deque` and `list` objects.